# P/T ContactForm Retrieving Custom fields Value after submitting form

Tags: form, plugin-contactform, custom

I'm trying to retrieve custom fields value after submitting a form. Trying to access the custom fields through the message element after the form is submitted always throws an error  that the custom fields variable does not exist.

Example that works:

```
<label for="fromName">Name:*</label>
<input id="fromName" type="text" name="fromName" value="{% if message is defined %}{{ message.fromName }}{% endif %}">`
```

Example that doesn't work (custom fields):

```
<label for="fromCompany">Company:</label>
<input id="fromCompany" type="text" name="message[fromCompany]" value="{% if message is defined %}{{ message.fromCompany }}{% endif %}">
```

Is it possible to retrieve custom field values after submitting the form?

Comment: Any update this this? I'd like to grab the current value, and also any error message associated with the custom field.

Comment: Has there been any development on this? Struggling to access additional fields in submitted forms (eg on return from error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just came across this question, for the sake of up to date info for others, it is now possible to do this with the latest release(1.7) of the ContactForm plugin from Pixel & Tonic:
https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm

```
<input id="fromCompany" type="text" name="message[fromCompany]" value="{% if message is defined %}{{ message.messageFields.['fromCompany'] }}{% endif %}">
```

Answer (score 3):

In `Craft 2.5` with `Contact Form 1.4` I'm receiving the same error when using:

```
{% if message is defined %}{{ message.contactTel }}{% endif %}
```

I've gotten around this by using the Craft Request method `getPost` which can return a post value from an array. In the case of the original question, the following should work:

```
<label for="fromCompany">Company:</label>
<input id="fromCompany" type="text" name="message[fromCompany]" value="{% if message is defined %}{{ craft.request.getPost('message.fromCompany') }}{% endif %}">
```