# P&T Contact Form Plugin - How to Retrieve the inserted values?

Tags: craft3, plugin-contactform

I have been looking for how to retrieve the inserted values when the submission is failed. Other than prepared fields (Name, Email, etc.), the inserted values disappear from the fields.

I already found this post, but those solutions did not work for me.
[P/T ContactForm Retrieving Custom fields Value after submitting form](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2629/p-t-contactform-retrieving-custom-fields-value-after-submitting-form)

My Craft is ver 3.7.50, Contact Form plugin is ver 2.5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contact form controller creates a [`Submission` model](https://github.com/craftcms/contact-form/blob/v2/src/models/Submission.php) with the submitted values and provides it to the template as a `message` variable. You should be able to access this variable inside your template like this:

```twig
{% set message = message ?? null %}
```

This message will contain the native properties (e.g. `fromName`, `fromEmail`):

```twig
{{ message.fromName }}
{{ message.fromEmail }}
```

If you use a single textarea field for the message body (`name="message"`), the value will be available as `message.message`:

```twig
{{ message.message }}
```

If you use multiple custom fields (`message[body]`, `message[phoneNumber]`), `message.message` will be an array with those fields:

```twig
{{ message.message.body }}
{{ message.message.phoneNumber }}
```

One notable caveat is that if you're inside an included template that is included with the option `with_context = false`, the `message` variable will *not* be available. In this case, you have to go through the route manager to access it:

```twig
{% set routeParams = craft.app.getUrlManager().getRouteParams() %}
{% set message = routeParams.message ?? null %}
```

Note that this applies to contact form plugin version <=3.0.0. For 3.0.0 and above, the variable has been renamed to `submission`, see the [changelog](https://github.com/craftcms/contact-form/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#300---2022-05-02) for details.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works as I wanted.